# Replace all strings beginning with colon like express route path

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, lodash

I have strings like this:

```
const a = '/example/:someItemUuid/hello'
const b = '/example/:someItemUuid/hello/:otherItemUuid'

const params = {
  someItemUuid: '12345',
  otherItemUuid: '67890'
}
```

I am looking for a simple way to pass:

`buildUrl(a, params)` and get `/example/12345/hello`

`buildUrl(b, params)` and get `/example/12345/hello/67890`

Is there a simple way library that exists that does this, or a simple way using lodash?

Comment: There a couple of string interpolation libraries out there. [interpolate-params](https://www.npmjs.com/package/interpolate-params), [interpolate-object](https://www.npmjs.com/package/interpolate-object), [string-interpolation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-interpolation).

Answer (score 2):

You need not to split and join. You can use replace and it's callback

[image]

```js
const a = '/example/:someItemUuid/hello'
const b = '/example/:someItemUuid/hello/:otherItemUuid'
const params = {someItemUuid: '12345',otherItemUuid: '67890'}

let replaceValues = (str,params) =>
  str.replace(/(^|\/):(\w+)(?=\/|$)/g, (m, g1, g2) => g1 + (params[g2] || m))

console.log(replaceValues(a,params))
console.log(replaceValues(b,params))
```

---

If your environment supports lookbehind also then you can use

```
`(?<=^|\/):(\w+)(?=\/|$)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  const fullLink = page.split('/').map(i => {
    if (i.match(/^:/)) return camelizePayload[i.replace(/^:/, '')]
    return i
  }).join('/')
```